# stop running php function if exceed a given time

Tags: php, performance, memory-leaks, time, while-loop

I need to parse many html files using php.

```
foreach($url_array as $url){

     $file = file_get_contents($url);

     parse_html($file);

}
```

For some reasons (file is too big), function parse_html() take very long time to run or has memory leak in it.

**I want to monitor function parse_html(). If the running time exceed a given time, should continue to parse the next url and disregard the current one.**

For most of the time, my codes runs great but there are some urls can not be parsed. There is no error output and I guess it is memory leak.

Comment: I suspect a different problem. What does `parse_html` look like? Can you post it?

Comment: I've never heard about memory leaks that make the PHP interpreter crash without notice. Is your environment configured to log/display errors?

Comment: parse_html is long and will call many other functions. parse_html will get part of whole html file, then get some paragraphs according given keywords array. Finally sort the paragraphs with a algorithm. In parse_html, I use str_get_html().  http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm   It is a PHP HTML DOM Parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can not be done as easily as you think. Since you are running on one thread only, you cannot have any checks. If this thread is blocking, it is blocking.

You need to create some sort of multi-threaded environment where you run one worker thread for the execution of `parse_html()` (to increase speed and take advantage of multi-core processors you could even spawn more worker threads) and another thread that checks and kills the workers if they are taking too much time.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I'll check Multitasking for PHP. I really don't want to use php to do this but our environment only allow PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Taking what [@klaus said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533485/stop-running-php-function-if-exceed-a-given-time/7533591#7533591) into account, you *would* be able to perform this check if you can edit the `parse_html()` function. Within the function, there are likely either a number of calls to various subfunctions or a large number of `for` repeat loops. You want to add a check somewhere in the functions, or at the head of the `for` loops, to see whether the function is taking too long to execute.

Simple pseudocode example:

```
function parse_html()
    start_time = 0;

    read file

    foreach element_to_be_parsed
        runtime = current_time - start_time
        if runtime > (whatever)
            break
        end

        ...do parsing stuff
    end
end
```

Comment: Good point, didn't consider her being able to edit the function. But it still doesn't give complete security (if there ever is something like this). If the leak/endless loop/etc happens within your `...do parsing stuff` pseudo-method, it wouldn't help. If I'd take that solution I would scatter the break-up condition into several parts of the function

Comment: Yeah, that's also a good point... for this to work, you'd need to know where the majority of time is being spent in the function, or else you'd still stall out, as you currently are. This approach works best if you're already familiar with the function, otherwise you'll spend a lot of time futzing around with where to put the timing checks.